How to detect when a Storekit Modal, or StoreKit Overlay is shown by ads in my app?
I am showing ads in my app that have the AppStore overlay/modal. Is there a way for me to detect when an ad shows that overlay in my app in production? I want to measure how often an ad shows the Storekit Modal, or StoreKit Overlay.
Is there a way to detect this?
Reference for Storekit and StoreKit Overlay from Vungle website:
https://support.vungle.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056673092-The-Liftoff-Monetize-Conversion-Experience#storekit-0-4

Found the information I was looking for:
For StoreKit Overlay there is a delegate callback.
storeOverlayDidFinishPresentation(_:transitionContext:)
Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skoverlaydelegate/3566707-storeoverlaydidfinishpresentatio
For SKStoreProductViewController there is a completion block in the loadProduct call:
    withParameters parameters: [String : Any],
    impression: SKAdImpression,
    **completionBlock** block: ((Bool, (any Error)?) -> Void)? = nil
)```


Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstoreproductviewcontroller/3951378-loadproduct


Thanks

